# Less - Overriding variables seems to dont work

Tags: less

i try to override some less variables but it seems to don`t work.
Here is how i wanna do it:

```
@hightlight-color-orange-01:    #ffbf7f;

@import 'customLess';
```

Content of customLess.less:

```
@hightlight-color-orange-01:    #d1b545;
```

But the style from the customLess.less is ignored.

Is there a way i can do that over `@import`?

Regards,
Kai

Comment: Has your LESS been recompiled? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Yes i have compiled it and no errors. When i remove the first definition for hightlight-color-orange-01 than the style from customLess.less is used.

Comment: Funny, when i do it over (ät)import "default_style";
@import "customLess"; where default_style holds the first definition than the definition from customLess overrides the default style..

Comment: Overriding variable should go *after* `@import` (in the code above you're overriding it up-side-down, e.g. your variable is overridden by those in the imported file). Read some related [tutorials](http://earthli.com/news/view_article.php?id=2965).

Comment: So the second solution from my last comment should be a valid solution for this problem or?

Comment: yes, due to last declaration wins for variables

Answer (score 1):

The Less language is just like CSS a declarative language. For variables lazy loading and the last declaration wins rule will applied.

So the following Less code:

```
p {
 color: @color;
}

@color: red; 
@color: yellow;
```

compiles into CSS as follows:

```
p {
color: yellow;
}
```

So you can use the `@color` before its declaration (lazy loading) and `@color` evaluates `yellow` everywhere in the code (last declaration wins).

Notice that `last declaration wins` only count for variables in the same scope (or better local scope can overrule the parent scope but NOT vice versa):

```
@value: global;

selector1 {
prop: @value;
}

selector2 {
@value: local;
prop: @value;
}
```

outputs:

```
selector1 {
  prop: global;
}
selector2 {
  prop: local;
}
```

Code from `@import` directive will be top bottom injected in the code and before applying the last declarations wins.